# Многопоточность и перезапись предыдущего print'а каждого потока

Tags: python, многопоточность

Есть два потока выполняющиеся одновременно, оба обрабатывают строки в разных файлах независимо друг от друга.
С каждого потока вывожу информацию :

```
print("Первый обработал " + row + " строк")
```

Пытаюсь исправить добавление новой строки на изменение предыдущей:

```
print("Первый обработал " + row + " строк", end = "r", flush = True)
```

но в таком случае оба потока меняют принты друг друга, есть возможность сделать так, что бы каждый поток изменял только "свой" принт, получая на выходе что - то типа:

> Первый поток обработал ХХХ строк

> Второй поток обработал ХХХ строй

Comment: Важное уточнение, забылся, проект реализую на корпоративной машине и добавление доп. библиотек настоящая проблема, вопрос в том, можно ли решить данный вопрос штатными средствами

Comment: _Важное уточнение_, изменить вопрос можно если не меняется смысл вопроса, или пока вам не дан первый ответ. В противном случае, следует задать новый вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Используя [`ESC`-последовательности](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), можно прыгать по строчкам.

Вот простая реализация, где строка вывода привязана к номеру потока, после выполнения вывода курсор перемещается на "базовую" строку. Сделал в виде прогрессбара, изменить формат вывода не составит труда.

```
import time
from random import random
from threading import Thread, Lock
from functools import partial

THREADS_COUNT = 5
NEED_STR = THREADS_COUNT + 1
print('\n' * NEED_STR, end=f"\x1b[{NEED_STR}F") # на случай, если на момент запуска не хватает строк терминала

print = partial(print, end='\r', flush=True)

plock = Lock()

def lprint(s, n):
    with plock:
        print(f"\x1b[{n}E") # перемещаемся вниз на n строк
        print(f"\t{s}")     # печатаем 
        print(f"\x1b[{n}F") # возвращаемся назад на n строк

def work(n, slow_down):
    lprint(f"thread {n}:", n)
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(slow_down)
        lprint(f"thread {n}: {'█' * i}", n)
    lprint(f"thread {n}: {'█' * i} finished!", n)

threads = []
print('Progress:')
for i in range(1, THREADS_COUNT + 1):
    t = Thread(target=work, args=(i, random()))
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads:
    t.join()

print(f"\x1b[{len(threads)}E", end='\n') # чтобы не затирался весь вывод после завершения программы
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [blessings](https://pypi.org/project/blessings/).

Пример из документации:

```
from blessings import Terminal

t = Terminal()

print t.bold('Hi there!')
print t.bold_red_on_bright_green('It hurts my eyes!')

with t.location(0, t.height - 1):
    print 'This is at the bottom.'
```

Comment: Спасибо, только узнал об этой библиотеке, есть что почитать
Но выше отписался, желательно штатными средствами, библиотеками решить этот вопрос

Answer (score 2):

В две строки надо подумать, но в одну строчку достаточно просто сделать с помощью `print()` и возврата каретки через `\r`, как у Вас указано, но должно быть `\r`.

В итоге можно сделать с двух потоков итоговую строку, и она будет обновляться с определенным интервалом по времени.

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    a = i
    b = i * 100
    print(f'thread 1 = {a}, thread 2 =  {b}', end='\r', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Запускать через терминал.

Если же в две строки, то можно с очисткой окна терминала тот же самый вариант прокрутить

```
import os
import time

for i in range(10):
    a = i
    b = i * 100
    os.system('clear')
    print(f'thread 1 = {a}\nthread 2 =  {b}', end='\n', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
```